# Auto mapping in ElasticSearch NEST client using underscore

Tags: elasticsearch, nest

ElasticSearch recommends to use underscores for field names. 
I'm using Nest client and I have the following type:

```
public class Employee
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}
```

Nest client offers a feature called auto mapping that can automatically infer the correct mappings from the properties of the POCO. If use this feature I will get:

```
"employee": {
    "properties": {
        "firstName": {
            "fields": {
                "keyword": {
                    "type": "keyword",
                    "ignore_above": 256
                }
            },
            "type": "text"
        },
        "lastName": {
            "fields": {
                "keyword": {
                    "type": "keyword",
                    "ignore_above": 256
                }
            },
            "type": "text"
        },
    }
}
```

But fields does not conform naming convention. There is another feature for defining own mappings using attributes. But I don't want to specify it manually for each field. So is there a possibility to configure client to use underscores for combining words by default?

Answer (score 1):

You can change the default field name inference of using camel casing to instead use snake casing through [`DefaultFieldNameInferrer(Func<string, string>)` on ConnectionSettings](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/current/field-inference.html#camel-casing)